# Display unordered list with custom bullets using angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to show each item of a list. In front of each item, I want to use '>>'. Can anyone tell me how to show '>>'.

For example,

```
    List1 

>> list1_item1    
>> list1_item2     
>> list1_item3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" >&gt;&gt; item.text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use Css for the symbol: ```:before { content: &gt;&gt; }```

Comment: Yes - thats a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the html character code: `&gt;`